# LINQ: Concating two lists and creating a new one doesnt seem to be bindable

Tags: linq, silverlight, binding

I'm trying to concat two lists and get a new anonymous one, then binding the one to a grid in silverlight for an app:

```
        var lst = 
            from games in AppLogic.CurrentApp.GAMES.Entities
            from playedGames in AppLogic.CurrentApp.PLAYEDGAMES.Entities.Where(f => f.GameID == games.ID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                ID = games.ID,
                Date = games.Date,
                MaxPoints = games.MaxPoints
            };

        dgGames.ItemsSource = lst;
```

But I always get a nullreferenceexception.
I've seen this syntax in another stackoverflow thread (sadly I didnt marked the url), but it doesnt seem to work this way.
Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or can't I just bind the new list like this?

The binding is like this:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <data:DataGrid x:Name="dgGames">
            <data:DataGrid.Columns>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Visibility="Collapsed" Binding="{Binding ID}" />
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Datum" Binding="{Binding Date}" />
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Punkte" Binding="{Binding MaxPoints}" />
                <!--<data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Gewinner" Binding="{Binding Winner}" />-->
            </data:DataGrid.Columns>
        </data:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

P.S.: As you can see I'm not even taking data from the left joined "PlayedGames", but it doesnt seem to work still.

Sorry in advance if there is something stupid wrong. I tinkered the code from some examples I found, so I cant be sure if they are even working.

Thanks alot for all answers!

Matthias

Comment: Since you're not taking data from the left-joined "PlayedGames", have you tried removing that line to see if the query works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewritting your left join this way.

```
var lst = from games in AppLogic.CurrentApp.GAMES.Entities
    join playedGames in AppLogic.CurrentApp.PLAYEDGAMES.Entities
    on game.ID equals games.GameID into JoinedGames
    from subGames in JoinedGames.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new                          
    {
       ID = games.ID,
       Date = games.Date,
       MaxPoints = games.MaxPoints                      
    };

dgGames.ItemsSource = lst.ToList();
```

Comment: Hm I built in a try catch and found this error message:
Message = "The query contains references to items defined on a different data context."
Seems like it isnt possible to combine to lists like this.

Would it be proper to make a own object just to combine them?

Comment: Sorry, Why are in 2 data context, are they from different databases?

Comment: According to my silverlight tutorial I have to create two classes like this:
    public class PLAYEDGAMES:DataContext
    {
        private const string CONNECTION_STRING = "isostore:/tblPLAYEDGAMEs.sdf";

        public Table<PLAYEDGAME> Entities;

        public PLAYEDGAMES()
            : base(CONNECTION_STRING)
        {
        }
    }

So one for playedgames and one for Games

Comment: If they are in 2 different databases then you can't combine queries that way. You would need to add ToList(), not sure if you need to do it for both entity lists. Try AppLogic.CurrentApp.GAMES.Entities.ToList() if it doesn't work apply it to PLAYEDGAMES.Entitites too.

Comment: So I just set the list at the page_load event and make basecally a list out of everything. Doenst seem that proper, but works.
Thanks!